# Join on get_where - is this possible?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table called `Listings` and a table called `wines` and one more called `wineinfo`

I originally was using the following to get the info from the `listings` table only, how ever since I restructured my DB, it requires the use of two other tables.

```
$listing = $this->db->get_where( "listings", [ "listingID" => $id ] 
)->row();

if( !$listing )
        throw new Exception("Error: Listing you're trying to bid on does not exist.", 1);

    // check not to bid on own listings
    if( $listing->list_uID == $userid )
        throw new Exception("Error: Dont't bid on your own listings.", 1);
```

I then tried changing the code so the JOIN statements could work

```
$this->db->select("FROM listings.*, Vintage, Vineyard, Wine_Name, Region, Advice, Grape,Producer,Type id,wine_id,Wine_Name,");
$this->db->from("wineinfo");
$this->db->where(["listingsID" => $id]);
$this->db->where(["wineinfo.wine_id" => "listings.wine_id"]);
$this->db->where(["wineinfo.Vintage" => "listings.wine_id"]);
$this->db->join("wines", "wineinfo.wine_id = wines.wine_id");
$listing = $this->db->get()->row();
```

I am being given this error.

`Unknown table 'listings'`

But there is 100% a table called listings.

I know I've missed something, or definitely messed up the code, I am only just learning about this and the code above worked for something else, but now I've amended it to this, it hasn't.

Comment: Am I reading this right that the listings table will join to the wineinfo table on both "wine_id" columns and also the "Vintage" column?

Comment: That is correct.

So the listings table has wine_id and Vintave.

It then matches them to wineinfo which also contains wine_id and then also wines. Each table contains data about the specific wine / vintage as wines have the same name but different vintages

Answer (score 1):

> I then tried changing the code so the JOIN statements could work

you are trying to combine 3 tables with 2 `FROM` and one `JOIN` clauses, which is incorrect the way you do it.

you need to keep `SELECT` clean, just select the columns you need, like:

```
$this->db->select("listings.*, wineinfo.*, wine.*");
```

then the `FROM` clause:

```
$this->db->from("wineinfo");
```

then make the joins:

```
$this->db->join("listings", "wineinfo.wine_id = listings.listingsID");
$this->db->join("wines", "wineinfo.wine_id = wines.wine_id");
```

followed by your where clauses.

**please note**, I don't know your table structure, so I can only guess your `JOIN` relationships. Also this is a simplified example, where I suppose that the 3 tables don't have matching column names.

**response to "ambiguous" comment:** you can limit your select clause to just necessary columns, e.g.

```
$this->db->select("listings.*, wineinfo.vintage, wine.*");
```

or use an alias:

```
$this->db->select("listings.*, wineinfo.wine_id as my_wineID, wine.*");
```

Answer (score 0):

The FROM in `$this->db->select("FROM listings.*, Vintage, Vineyard, Wine_Name, Region, Advice, Grape,Producer,Type id,wine_id,Wine_Name,");` is not supposed to be there.

The generated out query now looks like:

```
SELECT FROM *... FROM sometable
```

Comment: Just realised that was an error on my part when i was trying different things. I've updated my question to the correct error. thanks!